# Jenkins sshScript remote:remote pass argument

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, arguments

I have been trying to execute script in remote system through `sshScript remote:remote` by passing script `myscript.sh` two arguments `\\abc` and `xyz`, like this:

```
sshScript remote: remote, script: "myscript.sh \\abc xyz"
```

Is is failing in Jenkins, showing "`myscript.sh \abc xyz` does not exist".
I am new to Jenkins: Is there a way to execute the script?

Answer (score 2):

For testing, you can try and force the script to be considered as part of a command, using `bash -c '...'`:

```
def remote = [:]
remote.name = 'test'
remote.host = 'test.domain.com'
remote.user = 'root'
remote.password = 'password'
remote.allowAnyHosts = true
stage('Remote SSH') {
  sshCommand remote: remote, command: "bash -c 'myscript.sh \\abc xyz'"
}
```

The [OP T M Suhas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15914465/t-m-suhas) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67799703/jenkins-sshscript-remoteremote-pass-argument/67801415#comment119847143_67801415):

> `Myscript.sh` is in the Jenkins workspace(local system) and I want to avoid uploading `myscript.sh` to remote system and then execute it.

Then it needs to be `scp` to the remote server first, before being executed.

Comment: Tried it out but returns error :failed command with status 127, command not found. Do I have to make sure that the shell script is in the remote system before executing this command??

Comment: Myscript.sh is in the Jenkins workspace(local system) and I want to avoid uploading myscript.sh to remote system and then execute it.

Comment: @TMSuhas You will need to scp (ssh copy) it  first: I don't know how the remote server would execute it otherwise.